# Chrome extension : how to send submit?

Tags: form-submit

I have filled the field "searchstring" with my string.
How to send submit now?

`

```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: "document.forms[0]['searchstring'].value='B66956492'"
    })
  });     



</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follows:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: "document.forms[0]['searchstring'].value='B66956492',document.forms[0].submit();"
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but where should I place it in my code?(it should be submitted "ByClick" and after filled the field "searchstring")

Comment: Now I`ve got it:  code: "document.forms[0]['searchstring'].value='B66956492', document.forms[0].submit()"           THANKS!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added the complete code to the answer, just to be sure.